# Dockerfile overriding env var at "docker run" time

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV UID "1234"
ENV USERNAME "default"

RUN addgroup $USERNAME && useradd -u $UID -g $USERNAME -ms /bin/bash $USERNAME
CMD ["/usr/bin/id", "-u", "myname"]
```

and running docker via:

```
docker build -t setuser .    
docker run -e UID=5555 -e USERNAME=myname setuser
```

OUTPUT

```
/usr/bin/id: 'myname': no such user
```

this error tells me that `useradd` in Dockerfile was not executed during "docker run" time.

how could I achieve this?

`CMD ["/usr/bin/id", "-u", "default"]` works but i want to be able to supply the UID and USERNAME at run time, not at Dockerfile build time

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate [Henry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48611139/1924666)

Following portion of your Dockerfile executed when you build your image.

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV UID "1234"
ENV USERNAME "default"

RUN addgroup $USERNAME && useradd -u $UID -g $USERNAME -ms /bin/bash $USERNAME
```

So, this time, `UID=1234` & `USERNAME=default` are set.

When you run your image, It starts with ENTRYPOINT & CMD. It has no effect on `RUN addgroup $USERNAME ...`

So you need to run a script to use your passing ENV.

```
#!/bin/bash

addgroup $USERNAME && useradd -u $UID -g $USERNAME -ms /bin/bash $USERNAME

id -u $USERNAME
```

Here, your passing ENV values will be used.

Comment: so that shell script is what i put in as ENTRYPOINT? I think ENTRYPOINT is ran befor CMD

Comment: so the line id -u $USERNAME cannt be in Dockerfile? it needs to be in a script which would be executed via ENTRYPOINT?

Comment: ENTRYPOINT is the command which is executed when you run. You CMD holds parameter of that command.

Comment: By default, ENTRYPOINT is `/bin/bash`

Comment: when "addgroup $USERNAME && useradd -u $UID -g $USERNAME -ms /bin/bash $USERNAME" is in docker-entrypoint.sh, it cannot find addgroup. addgroup: command not found

Comment: it works under RUN in dockerfile. what's the difference between RUN and within a ENTRYPOINT script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164575/discussion-between-aerokite-and-ealeon).

Answer (score 1):

The useradd was executed when the image was created. If you want to run some commands when the container is started put them into a script that is executed at start time.